# Transition on position:absolute header and background

Tags: html, css, image, header, hover

I'm trying to apply a hover state to some portfolio navigation. It's a horizontally and vertically centered header on top of an image. The centering works as I need it to (there are reasons for it being as complicated as it is, or believe me, I would do it some other way).

But the hover state is giving me problems. I'm trying to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/33/. Which is a transition of the `h2` and its background on hover of the image. I can get it almost working by fiddling with opacity or the z-index of the `h2`, but especially the change of the background color is not working (because there are no elements exactly covering the image, of which I can change the background). Does anyone know how to get the hover state working properly?

This is the code I have and on which I'm trying to get this hover effect to work:

*(Also posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/34/)*

HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="img-crop">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/gUKbAE" /></a>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-crop {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the issue really is, what specifically is the desired outcome?

Comment: I would like to apply a hoverstate as outlined in the fiddle above. And in doing so I would like to retain the vertically and horizontally centered header on top of the image (without specifying dimensions, so as it is now: a dynamic centering). Also, I would like to retain the hiding of the overflow of the image as it exceeds screen width, and keep the way the header centers on screen width if that is smaller than the image. It's a lot to explain, but I hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the question by doing it like this:

HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="title"><h2>Title</h2></a>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;  
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear;  
    -o-transition: color 0.2s linear;  
    transition: color 0.2s linear; 
}

.title {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;  
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;  
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;  
    transition: background-color 0.2s linear; 
}

.title:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.item:hover .title {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.item:hover h2 {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8ZXW/). That way it's dynamic (the image is fluid and there are no fixed heights or widths to it) and the headline is automatically centered vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

h2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This could be it!

Comment: That's almost it. If you change the hoverstate to: article:hover h2 {opacity:1;}, it will also trigger even if you're not directly hovering the h2. But I would also like the image to darken, because otherwise the header might not be readable. If I try to solve this by setting a background to the h2, it doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Basically what I need to do is get an element in front of the img and behind the h2, so I can use `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` to darken it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Okay I'm on it, Some month ago I was needing exactly the same for my own portfolio I never ended don BTW...

Comment: Yeah, mine is a bit of a neverending story as well.

Comment: I think this (http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/37/) sort of works, but do you know why it extends underneath on hover? (i.e., the hover is not exactly the same size as the image?)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to make sure following things.

1. your h2 should be exactly equal to the container behind, only then it will perform a total overlay.
2. set the default `opacity` of `h2` to be 0. and change/transition it to some mid value say 0.6 upon `hover`.
3. now also, you need to make the  `background-color` of the h2 black, or different than the parent container, only then it will appear.
4. and then give appropriate padding to the h2 element, to make the text appear in the middle.

set `h2` like this:

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top:20%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;

    opacity:0;
}
```

and set your `h2:hover` like this:

```
h2:hover
{
    padding-top:20%;
    color:white;
    background-color:Black;
    opacity:0.6;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s, background-color 0.25s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.25s, background-color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s, background-color 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.25s, background-color 0.25s;
    -kthtml-transition: opacity 0.25s, background-color 0.25s;
    transition: opacity 0.25s, background-color 0.25s;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/35/)

Comment: Problem is, I cannot use fixed heights for this project. It requires me to base the height on the dimensions of the img (which are dynamic). And I guess this would only work on fixed height images. Any ideas for a dynamic solution?

Comment: so what? your h2 should cover entire parent div container right? if it covers parent div, it will cover the image, since image is inside the div. and you have given 100% height to the h2. so there should be no problem i guess

Comment: Well that's the problem, the h2 doesn't cover the entire parent, only the bottom 50% of it. That's the way it's centered vertically without setting an explicit height. So that's why I cannot use the h2's background for the transition.