# Why does this background extend beyond the image upon hover?

Tags: html, css, image, header, hover

I'm trying to create a hover effect on a rather complex layout. The hover effect works, but upon hover the background (or overlay) extends beyond the image (I would like it to be just as big as the image).

Does anyone know why that is and how to fix it?

HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="img-crop">
        <a href="#" class="title-anchor"><h2>Title</h2></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/gUKbAE" /></a>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title-anchor {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-crop:hover .title-anchor {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.img-crop {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2 {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-crop:hover h2 {
    color: black;
}
```

It's here too: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/39/

Comment: I don't think it's any margins or padding, since I've already disabled those and the effect was still there.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904693

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transition on position:absolute header and background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904693/transition-on-positionabsolute-header-and-background)

Comment: @xec, I solved my previous question, but couldn't figure this bit out. It's a different problem in my opinion, though somewhat part of the previous one. You can delete my previous question if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this on the universal css:

```
img { border: 0; vertical-align: top;}
```

...

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/kmjRu/43/

Comment: Images will be vertical aligned with the baseline of text, which causes spacing at the bottom

Comment: NP! This has become a html5 boilerplate standard (vertical-align):
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css

Comment: I think I prefer your answer because it doesn't require me to mess with the display mode. Close call though, both work.

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
img {
display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/41/

Images are [replaced inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element) by default

Answer (score 0):

define the height of  .img-crop:hover the same as .img-crop img. E.g.

```
.img-crop:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 100px;
}
.img-crop img{height: 100px;}
```